# Powershell Passing in Array to Function Error Empty

Tags: arrays, function, powershell

I created an array of custom objects using the following code:

```
$LOTR = @()
$myObject = new-object PSObject
$myObject | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name GroupName - Value $city.name
$myObject | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name GroupType - Value $city.type
$LOTR += $myObject

$LOTR (after iterations):

GroupName      GroupType
----------     ----------
Aragon          Gondor
Arwen           Rivendell
```

I want to pass `$LOTR` into a function I wrote that would compare if more than one Gondor `GroupType` exists. Below is a funciton to check if the array passed successfully.

```
function Comparison {
    param ({[Parameter(Mandatory-=$True)[string[]]$myarray})
    write-host $myarray
}
```

My problem is that when I try to pass `$LOTR` I get an error `Cannot bind argument to parameter 'myarray' because it is an empty array`

What am I doing wrong? I've tried using forcing the function to accept empty arrays, and it is empty. But printing the `$LOTR` on the powershell command line returns all the values I inputted. I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: Is the space `- Value` here a typo? Something is also wrong with your function syntax

Answer (score 0):

Your code works (*sort of*) if I make some changes to your syntax

```
$myObject | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name GroupName - Value $city.name
```

Should be the following with the space removed before `Value`

```
$myObject | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name GroupName -Value $city.name
```

And I updated the function to look like this. Removing the hyphen after mandatory and the curly braces. The formatting is just for readability

```
function Comparison{
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string[]]$myarray)
    write-host $myarray
}
```

As to why you are casting is to a string array I dont know.

I get the following output with your test data

```
@{GroupName=Aragon; GroupType=Gondor} @{GroupName=Arwen; GroupType=Rivendell}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix, the error is gone. However, when I print $myarray from inside the function, it is still empty. Should I be using something else other than string array?

Comment: @HeyJude that all depends on what you are doing with the data.

Comment: Since $LOTR is an array of custom objects, remove `[string[]]` from the Comparison function since it's not an array of strings. If you really need a type declaration (you don't) use `[System.Array]` or `[System.Object[]]`